# Keydown Event in JAWS / IE11 not firing properly

Tags: javascript, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

We are working on fixing some accessibility issues on our video player, one of which is the ability to scrub through the video with the keyboard. We have the following code, which pauses the video on keydown and scrubs the video forward/backward and then on keyup it plays the video at the new point.

The issue is that in IE11 with JAWS the keydown event does not keep firing while the key is held down. It goes back and forth between keydown and keyup. The result is an endless loop of moving one second forward and then going back to the original point in the video and playing.

Here is the code that we are using currently, is there anything that we can do to make this work with JAWS?

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) {
      if (ev.keyCode === 37 || ev.keyCode === 39) {
        console.log("keydown");
      }
    });

document.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev) {
      if (ev.keyCode === 37 || ev.keyCode === 39) {
      console.log("keyup");
    });
```

happy to add any additional information you may need or to answer any questions, just let me know

Comment: Can you try this ? Before pressing and sustaining left or right arrow, press insert+3. Does it work now ? If yes then there's no solution. Please tell the result of this test so that I can post a more complete answer and explain why.

Comment: @QuentinC      This did not work, is there anything else that you'd like for me to try?

Comment: No, I haven't another idea yet. Can you post a link to your page ? It will be easier to try myself.

Comment: @QuentinC I cannot put the link to the page on here because of corporate policy, but did simplify the code so that it could be pasted in the console on IE11. Will that work for you? I really appreciate your help, please let me know if there is anything else that I can do, happy to do all that I can within my security policy.

Comment: Can't you post a simplified version on a platform like jsfeedle ? The video or audio probably don't matter. In the meantime you can still try this: can you tell how much time passes between the keydown and the keyup event ? I suspect it to be almost instantaneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is to do with how JAWs intercepts key presses and uses a virtual cursor.

When pressing left and right it is attempting to say the previous and next character and so it intercepts the key press, does the action and passes the left arrow key to the browser once as it is in 'document browsing mode'.

One way to stop this behaviour is to use `role="application"` and this signals screen readers to pass all information through to the browser normally.

Obviously you need to read all the documentation on `role="application"` as you could introduce accessibility issues rather than fix them if you aren't careful!

### Relevant W3 Guidance

[W3 Role - application information](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/roles#application)

> When the user navigates an element assigned the role of application, assistive technologies that typically intercept standard keyboard events SHOULD switch to an application browsing mode, and pass keyboard events through to the web application. The intent is to hint to certain assistive technologies to switch from normal browsing mode into a mode more appropriate for interacting with a web application; some user agents have a browse navigation mode where keys, such as up and down arrows, are used to browse the document, and this native behavior prevents the use of these keys by a web application.